# I'm getting the following error after resetting my phone

Tags: factory-reset, system-error

I have reset my phone due to hanging issue. After resetting my phone, I got this error screen while restarting. How to solve this problem.

[image: photo]

Error message translated: "unfortunately com.android.phone has stopped working".

The phone model is Moto G 3rd generation.

Answer (score 2):

It should help to reset again so the Setup wizard could be reinitialized and completed successfully. I've had this problem several times flashing ROMs and booting after installing GApps without clearing the data partition.

Follow these steps:

1. Do a factory reset, by booting into recovery. Steps:

   - Power off your phone.
   - Hold “<kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>” for at-least 3 seconds and then release the buttons.
   - Now Use <kbd>Volume down</kbd> key to highlight “Recovery” on the bootloader menu, and then press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> key to select and boot into recovery mode.
2. After reset, go through the setup process while being connected to the internet (WiFi or 3g] and login to your gmail account. -- This is very important.

If that does not solve your issue, flashing a **factory image** is a sure shot way of solving this error.

---

Though it might sound strange what the Google-Login should have to do with the dialer, here's what [Dan Brown](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/116168/dan-brown) points out (in a now deleted comment):

> Trust me; it makes all the difference sometimes. There appear to be invisible triggers that the setup wizard trips that can cause a device to bug out. In Older Samsung tablets, The Moto G series, and other devices tend to have one of these triggers activated when you sign into Google via setup. Much more prominent on custom ROMs. If that's not it, it's possible that the system is bugging out when retrieving contacts from the Google cloud (because no account was signed in) and throws a fit about it.
>
> I remember one of my old Q's where I had no notifications: That was from an incomplete setup. It makes sense, in an odd way: You don't finish the setup, stuff goes wrong. GApps part of the setup? Better do that then!